# Adding frames to gifs using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following code

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %script_id%_tmp_img_*1.png') do (
    ffmpeg -y -v error -i %%i -i %script_id%_tmp_blank_frame.png -filter_complex "overlay" overlayed_%%i
    del %%i
)
```

It currently Adds a overlay image frame at every 10th frame EX , 1,11,21,31 ect ect anything that ends in *1 any advice how i would change this so instead it adds 8 overlay frames before the gif then 1 after the gif instead? Any help would be great i am super stuck thanks :)

EDIT Heres the full code

```
:: Usage composegif.bat <file> [-cut <seconds, max 14, set as default>] [-fps <fps, default 10>] [-blank <png file name>]
:: The extra frame is a png named "blank_frame_orig.png" or a custom name can be passed as a parameter, 
:: any dimension is ok, it will be resized and overlayed to the original frame
:: The frame is added as first and every 10 after that, so 1, 11, 21...
:: If you want to edit that , search "FREQUENCY" in this file and edit the line below

@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set script_id=%random%
set max_time=15

if "%1" == "" (
    echo Select a file to transform
    exit 
)

if not exist %1 (
    echo File not found
    exit
)

::set params

set input_file=%1
set framerate=20
set blank_frame=blank_frame_orig.png
set cut_sec=%max_time%

:loop
if not "%2"=="" (
    if "%2"=="-fps" (
        set framerate=%3
        shift
    )
    if "%2"=="-cut" (
        if not "%3"=="" (
            if "%3" GTR "%max_time%" ( 
                echo Max output is %max_time% seconds
            ) else ( 
                set cut_sec=%3
            )
        ) else (
            set cut_sec=%max_time%
        )
        shift
    )
    if "%2"=="-blank" (
        set blank_frame=%3
        shift
    )
    shift
    goto :loop
)

echo Fps set to %framerate%
echo Cutting gif at %cut_sec% seconds

::extract images
echo Extracting images
ffmpeg -v error -i %input_file% -vsync 0 %script_id%_tmp_img_%%03d.png || del %script_id%_tmp_*

::get size from first frame
for /f %%i in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries stream^="width,height" -of csv^=p^=0:s^=\: %script_id%_tmp_img_001.png') do (
    set size=%%i
)

::resize blank frame
echo Size is %size%
ffmpeg -v error -y -i %blank_frame% -vf scale=%size% %script_id%_tmp_blank_frame.png || del %script_id%_tmp_*

::add overlay to frames and removing corresponding ones
echo Adding overlay to every 10th frame
:: EDIT THIS TO CHANGE FREQUENCY
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %script_id%_tmp_img_*1.png') do (
    ffmpeg -y -v error -i %%i -i %script_id%_tmp_blank_frame.png -filter_complex "overlay" overlayed_%%i
    del %%i
)

::rename overlayed frames
rename "overlayed_*" "//////////*"

::create gif at 'framerate' fps
set finalFileName=%overlayed%_%random%.gif
echo Creating gif %finalFileName%
ffmpeg -v error -framerate %framerate% -i %script_id%_tmp_img_%%003d.png -t 00:00:%cut_sec% %finalFileName%  || del %script_id%_tmp_*


::delete tmp files
del %script_id%_tmp_*

echo Done
```

but this code adds the overlay.png every 10th frame of the gif EX 1,11,21,31,41 ect instead i want it to add 19 of them before the gif then 1 after

Comment: You want to show each image individually, or all at once? How long should each image display for?

Comment: i just want to make overlay.png then have it show say 19 Overlay images then the gif then 1 overlay.png after length dont matter i just want atleast So many frames before the gif and 1 after

Comment: I updated my question with the full code :)

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. Do you have a link to an example video that does what you want?

Comment: Sure heres an example of the output and what it would look like the overlay image 19 frames of it then the gif then 1 overlay image at the end https://i.imgur.com/qWMrX1m.gif

Comment: "overlay" means to use the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) to place one image or video over another. It appears that you want to use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). Search `[ffmpeg] concat filter is:answer` for more than 100 answers.